# how to batch dialog dataset in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to do a task oriented dialog chatbot which is used to book restaurant.Because every dialog has different sequences(eg. some has 5 turns of dialogs which is 10 sentences while another may has 6 turns of dialogs which is 12 sentences totally),I don't know how to batch dataset.

Could you give me some tutorial or github example?

Answer (score 1):

There are some related questions to this on Stackoverflow. I liked the explanation/answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030782/why-do-we-pack-the-sequences-in-pytorch). The tldr version is to use [Packed Sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=rnn#torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence). [The answer I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030782/why-do-we-pack-the-sequences-in-pytorch) provides the following example (copied from the link):

```
a = [torch.tensor([1,2,3]), torch.tensor([3,4])]
b = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(a, batch_first=True)
>>>>
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 3,  4,  0]])
torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(b, batch_first=True, lengths=[3,2])
>>>>PackedSequence(data=tensor([ 1,  3,  2,  4,  3]), batch_sizes=tensor([ 2,  2,  1]))
```