# Why do we need pack_padded_sequence() when we have pack_sequence()?

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

After reading the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030782/why-do-we-pack-the-sequences-in-pytorch) question I'm still a bit confused about the whole PackedSequence object thing. As I understand it, this is an object optimized for parallel processing of variable sized sequences in recurrent models, a problem to which zero padding is one [imperfect] solution. It seems that given a PackedSequence object, a Pytorch RNN will process each sequence in the batch to its end, and not continue to process the padding. So why is padding needed here? Why are there both a pack_padded_sequence() and pack_sequence() methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly for historical reasons; `torch.nn.pack_padded_sequence()` was created before `torch.nn.pack_sequence()` (the later appeared in `0.4.0` for the first time if I see correctly) and I suppose there was no reason to remove this functionality and break backward compatibility.

Furthermore, it's not always clear what's the best/fastest way to `pad` your input and it highly varies on data you are using. When data was somehow padded beforehand (e.g. your data was pre-padded and provided to you like that) it is faster to use `pack_padded_sequence()` (see [source code of `pack_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/rnn.html#pack_sequence), it's calculating `length` of each data point for you and calls `pad_sequence` followed by `pack_padded_sequence` internally). Arguably `pad_packed_sequence` is rarely of use right now though.

Lastly, please notice `enforce_sorted` argument provided since `1.2.0` version for both of those functions. Not so long ago users had to sort their data (or batch) with the longest sequence first and shortest last, now it can be done internally when this parameter is set to `False`.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `pad_packed_sequence` obsolete? How does one unpack one's `PackedSequence` object?
I wrote the following lambda which works for me. Is there a better way?  

`unpack = lambda packed_seq_obj: [tnsr[:ln] for tnsr, ln in zip(*pad_packed_sequence(packed_seq_obj, batch_first=True))]`

Comment: It's not obsolete and my mentioning of it was a typo, sorry. That's one way to do it, it depends what you are willing to do with it (sometimes there is no need to `unpack` e.g. when you need last timestamp). Your code for unpacking is the way to go, there is no built-in functionality for that AFAIK.